# How to use git status, reset, revert with overleaf git project?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, git

Is there a way to use git commands with an overleaf project? Currently, I see an option to push and pull from github, but nothing more. I have workaround (listed below) for some commands, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it instead?

1. `git status`: not able to use as of now.
2. `git reset` : delete the overleaf project and re-import the project from github.
3. `git revert` : clone the project from github on local pc, do the revert, push the changes. and then pull those changes into overleaf.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) The GitHub syncing feature has more of a point-and-click interface for pushing/pulling changes from GitHub. (Similar to editing files and making commits directly in the GitHub UI itself.) If you want to use git commands directly, you may want to use Git Bridge, instead of GitHub sync. With Git Bridge you can create a local repository where you use standard git commands. Then Overleaf functions as a remote, without needing to use GitHub as an intermediary. More information at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub#The_Overleaf_Git-Bridge

Comment: Thanks @PaulGessler for responding. I can't use the git bridge, since the project simply does not compile on my local and prefer to use overleaf instead of local project anyway. I wish there was a better way :(

Comment: It would be good to understand your workflow better. What are you using GitHub sync for if no one is working offline? Feel free to contact us at support@overleaf.com if you don’t want to give details publicly.

Comment: I am just using overleaf with github.com since I wanted to track my changes. No one else is using my repo, but often new additions break my pdf and I'd like to go back without losing my changes and see what caused the problem. for example, i added some new citations and 1 of them had special characters which broke my pdf. with the help of git it is much easier to deal with such issues. where i can go back to a version which was working fine. and also narror down on what might be causing the problem. therefore i do small commits every now and then.

Answer (score 3):

I am using the workflow here:[Creating an Overleaf project from an existing Git repository](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub#The_Overleaf_Git-Bridge)

In the steps listed there, you use `git revert` to overwrite the files originally created in the blank Overleaf project, so I suppose, that command does work, at least in this first series of steps.

Following the tutorial, my resulting setup is as follows:

```bash
❯ git remote -v
origin  https://username@git_hostname/~username/original_latex_project.git (fetch)
origin  https://username@git_hostname/~username/original_latex_project.git (push)
overleaf    https://git.overleaf.com/project_hash (fetch)
overleaf    https://git.overleaf.com/project_hash (push)
```

My workflow is to

1. Edit my project files either on Overleaf, from an local copy of the repo using any editor, or from the web UI of my git repo host
2. Commit changes in the editing location (this is done automatically by overleaf when a request hits the Git-Bridge I believe, as long as your recent edit is saved with "ctrl/cmd-s" or compile)
3. Do one of the following:

- `pull overleaf` and `push origin` if the edit was made "on a
  remote" using Overleaf (swap if made on git web UI) or alternately
- `push origin` and `push overleaf` if the edit was made in the local repository
  using emacs/vim/vscode etc.

This really covers all the stuff I need to do - kudos to the Overleaf team on the nice integration.

However, I will note, and this may be relevant to your questions @vipin8169, that the the Overleaf repository maintained by the Git-Bridge will refuse a `git push -f`. This means that operations that rewrite history on the `master`/`main` branch, say, a `git rebase`, will fail to push.

That said, I don't mind the forced compliance with such a good practice, and to be honest the editing history is a freebie space wise so If you really need to clean up history for public release or other reasons, you can simply clean up the local/other github manager copy of your project, delete the old Overleaf project (or just create a new one!) and then follow the exact same starting steps in my first link to get a clean looking history reconnected to Overleaf.

Answer (score 0):

I have linked Overleaf with Dropbox. Now I can use git traditionally via the local Dropbox integration. If you change the branch you have to wait for Dropbox to sync, then you will also see the changes in Overleave.